# C++ multi chat server

Tags: c++, c++11, network-programming

I am trying to write a multi chat server without using threads. I came across `select()` but I am having hard time understanding how can I read a client request and send it right away when the `send()` blocks and the client socket might not be ready to be written and by this losing the server parallel io ability.

```
If(fd_isset(socket,&read_fds){
    Recv()
    SendMesgToRequestedClient()
}
```

I thought a possible solution is to save each client a list of pending messages and send them on `fd_isset(socket,&write_fds)` but then instead of saving CPU I might use a ton of memory.

Comment: So you don't send right away - you use `select` to wait until the socket is writable. A traditional blocking server would use the exact same amount of memory, sitting in the buffers of the blocked `send` calls (plus the overhead of maintaining multiple threads). That, too, is a form of queueing.

Comment: So in that case i wait until he is writable and then send the message, but a certain client might get a number of messages from diffrent clients. Is it okay to save a list of messgaes to each client and send them when he is writable? Or thier is a better way

Comment: Well, I'm not in a position to design your application for you. That said, your approach sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! :)

Comment: Sockets can be made *non*-blocking.